# how to check JDK install with javac command

Tags: java, javac

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\G6>javac -version
'javac' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\G6>
```

Comment: Make sure you have the file path to `javac` in your `PATH`. Also, some information regarding you environment would be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

it means that javac.exe is not in your PATH.

you can either include the installed Java in your PATH or to call java.exe from its directory.

for the first option, see http://windowsitpro.com/systems-management/how-can-i-add-new-folder-my-system-path